# Iterating from XML and saving data to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm iterating over a XML file and trying to save the each data to the database, but it's not saving in my table. Iterating and retrieving data from XML is working fine.

Controller:

```
List<ListingsModel> xlist = new List<ListingsModel>();

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/xml/listing.xml"));

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("/Listings/Listing"))
{
    xlist.Add(new ListingsModel
                  {
                      Ad_Type = node["Type_Type"].InnerText,
                       Unit_Type = node["Unit_Type"].InnerText
                  });
}

AppTestDBConn db = new AppTestDBConn();

listing tbllisting = new listing();
ListingsModel mymodel = new ListingsModel();

tbllisting.listtype = mymodel.Ad_Type;
tbllisting.communityName = mymodel.Community;

db.listings.Add(tbllisting);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Model class:

```
public class ListingsModel
{
    public string Ad_Type { get; set; }
    public string Unit_Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Specify the language you are using here. C#?

Comment: yes Im using C#

Answer (score 0):

You're reading all of your xml into `xlist`, but after that you're not using that list. Instead a new `ListingsModel` is created and added to the db.

Change your code to

```
List<ListingsModel> xlist = new List<ListingsModel>();

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/xml/listing.xml"));
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("/Listings/Listing"))
{
    xlist.Add(new ListingsModel
    {
        Ad_Type = node["Type_Type"].InnerText,
        Unit_Type = node["Unit_Type"].InnerText
    });
}

AppTestDBConn db = new AppTestDBConn();
db.listings.AddRange(xlist);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I also recommend adding some exception handling.

**UPDATE**

according to error message OP uses different classes for the xml loading and entity. You need to convert between the two before doing the AddRange. Since you didn't supply the classes I can't tell you how to do that.

Also fixed an error in the code, forgot to add the dbset to the context (`db.listings.AddRange(xlist)`)

Comment: db.AddRange(xlist) is showing an error "Cannot Convert from System.collections.Generic.List<Model-Class-I-Created-for-XML> to System.collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Model-class-created-by-EF>